# Modifying a bijective function.

Tags: analysis

If $f$ is a bijection from $X$ to $\{i \in \mathbb{N}: i < n\}$
and I define a function 
$$g:X -\{x\} \rightarrow \{i \in \mathbb{N}: i < n-1\}$$
such that $g(y) = f(y)$ if $f(y) < f(x)$ and $g(y) = f(y) -1$ if $f(y) > f(x)$

How would I show $g$ is a bijection?

I have began by saying that if $f(y) < f(x)$ then we are done, as $f$ is a bijection and $g(y) = f(y).$

If $f(y) > f(x)$...

It seems obvious but i can't seem to put pen to paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with your two cases.

First note that $$\left|X\setminus\{x\}\right|=\left|\{i\in\mathbb{N}:i<n-1\}\right|<\infty.$$

Since we have a function, $g$, from a finite set to another finite set of the same cardinality, we only need to show that $g$ is injective *or* surjective.

To show that $g$ is surjective let $k\in\{i\in\mathbb{N}:i<n-1\}$.  If $k<f(x)$ then $g\circ f^{-1}(k)=k$.  If $k\geq f(x)$ then $g\circ f^{-1}(k+1)=k$.  In either case $k$ is in the image of $g$ and we have that $g$ is surjective.